# Bash PS1 Doesn't Evaluate Variables

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to set my PS1 prompt to

```
/usr/local/src mario
```

So I've used the following code inside of .bash_profile:

```
export PS1=" \w \u\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

And I end up with:

```
 \w \u\[$(tput sgr0)\]
```

Ideas?

I can use string concatenation to get what I want but that seems very odd that I need to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Bash? I can't reproduce the `\w` etc.

Comment: How would I verify?  I think you are right.  I ran `bash` and then reran the source on `.bash_profile` and it seems to have worked.  I'm not sure what it was running if it wasn't Bash.  Thanks

Comment: Well, start Bash with `bash`, try it there, and if that works, your login shell is probably not Bash. Also, check `/etc/passwd` for the shell entry on the line with your username.

Comment: Typically, you put the prompt in `.bashrc` and don't export it.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer and expanded on another issue+solution.

Comment: You can (ought to be able to) change your default shell with `chsh`.

Comment: Also consider nixing the `export` of `PS1`, as what suits `bash` will be gibberish in another shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell is likely not `bash`. Change it with `chsh`.

Also, there's a problem with part of the `$PS1` value:

```
PS1=" \w \u\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

The `$(...)` will be evaluated when you set `PS1`, but just that one time.  If you would like to execute `tput sgr0` every time the prompt displays, use single quotes:

```
PS1='\w \u\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$ '
```

(I have also moved the initial space from the start to the end of the value and added `\$` which will make the prompt and command line more readable.

You could also set

```
PS1="\w \u \$ "
```

and then set

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="tput sgr0"
```

to have `tput sgr0` execute before displaying every prompt (I don't know if it makes sense to do this as I don't quite know what it does, but the facility for it is there).

Notice that neither `PS1` nor `PROMPT_COMMAND` needs to be exported as it only makes sense to set them for the current shell session.

Comment: `tput sgr0` is used to reset terminal attributes like display color. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed *before* the prompt is displayed, and the `tput` command is presumably used to undo changes made earlier in the prompt (but not shown).

Comment: @chepner Ah, but now they know about `PROMPT_COMMAND` in any case, if they would find *that* useful for something.